# Failed to load "com.google.android.gms.r styleable"

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I want to integrate admob in my application. I am trying to run the testing code at https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start.

My current google-play-service version is 32. Previously I was working on version 29. Since google has splited the play_service library into multiple libraries, i used to select and extract from each library store at m2repository. Currently I have selected play-services-ads-lite-9.0.0 .jar. This is the only jar file I have included in my project. When I run the code, app crashes. No warnings or errors in compiler.

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.richa.salemob"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:allowBackup="true"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <activity android:name=".Start">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application></manifest>
```

My Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.richa.salesmob"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/white">
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

My Java Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.start);
MobileAds.initialize(StartFields.context, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new
AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
init();
}
```

I am unable to understand and resolve the error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.richa.India_Sales-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Please help. Thank you

Comment: paste the gradle file

Comment: i don't have a gradle file. I am making this code for Api level 9, the minimum required for AdMob using Intellij as normal android application.

Comment: 11 hours and still not any answer :( Please somebody have a look

Comment: You should try using [android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) to make android apps, this will help you compile [dependencies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#verify_app-level_buildgradle_excerpt) easier. Add the google-play-service and all dependencies required to use adMob. Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't want to use Gradle right now, please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39178361/6562713), its an elaborate explanation of my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong app id, you have to get a new individual id

> To find your app ID, click the App management option under the
>   settings dropdown (located in the upper right-hand corner) on the
>   AdMob account page. App IDs have the form
>   ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~NNNNNNNNNN.

Comment: This is for testing and according to the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start) we can use this id. As per them, **Note that the ad unit ID provided above is just for testing. It allows you to retrieve a sample banner ad and make sure your implementation is correct. You should always use test ads when developing and testing your app.**